# Chain non-jquery methods in a jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I write a jquery plugin that has a method that adds two values and sets the html to that value.  I can chain it one way, but not the other and I want to understand why, and how I can make sure I can chain both ways.

```
$.fn.foo = function() {
    this.result = 0;

    this.doMath= function(a, b) {
        this.result = a + b;
        this.html(this.val);
        return this;
    }

    return this;
}

var link = '<a href="#">Link</a>'
// works as expexted
var a = $(link).foo().doMath(1,2).appendTo('body')
// does not work, likely because appendTo returns jquery
var b = $(link).foo().appendTo('body').doMath(1,2)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j7ut1f30/1/

Comment: jQuery frequently constructs new jQuery objects in the background. As you suspect, it's because of `.appendTo()`, which must be making a new object, so the function you added directly to the object in `foo()` is lost. You don't get an error, because the actual jQuery `.add()` is being called.

Comment: Don't think you realize that `this` in plugin is jQuery also

Comment: The solution depends your intent. You could use `.data()`, but that is tied to an element. If that's the association you want, then you're set. I wouldn't add a function though. I'd just add the numbers you want, and create your own methods with names other than `.add()` or `.val()`, since that'll break things.

Comment: @charlietfl add and val were bad choices for this example

Comment: OK...but `doMath()` isn't  a `$.fn` property. The only reason it worked the first time is you are actually adding the property directly to the jQuery object which isn't how you should do things

Comment: @squint can you expand on the data method? All I am after is chaining inherited jquery and my own added methods. That is all.

Comment: @Tester232323: The `.data()` was about your specific example, so that you could put your methods on the `.prototype` and pass the `result` along without relying on a closure. Since the `.data()` method lets you associate arbitrary data with a DOM element, it could be useful as long as the DOM element being operated on doesn't change between `foo()` and `doMath()`. I'll post an example in a minute.

Comment: [Here's a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/j7ut1f30/2/). But again, the `.data()` is tied to the element(s) in the collection
.

Answer (score 0):

After 2 weeks of trying everything, I finally acheived my goals.

```
class $Util {

    static $wrapper(self) {
        if (!self.$wrapper)
            throw new ReferenceError('$Util.$wrapper: $wrapper not defined in context of first argument');
        $.each($Util.jqueryPrototype, function(i, e) {
            self[e] = function() {
                self.$wrapper[e](...arguments);
                return self;
            }
        });
    }
}

$Util.jqueryPrototype = Object.getOwnPropertyNames($.prototype);

class foo {
    constructor() {
        this.$wrapper = $('p')
        $Util.$wrapper(this);
        return this;
    }
    test() {
        console.log('j')
        return this;
    }
}
var s = new foo();
s.css('color', 'red').test().appendTo('body').test().css('color','green')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/24r6uxs1/